# How to copy a subset of SQL objects across databases within a transaction?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

We already have a `.dtsx` package to copy a subset of tables (about 20) from one database to another (at least once in every month). It is using "Transfer SQL Server Objects Task". However this does not handle transactions [See here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/368ee5da-db95-48a8-a445-c9dce5dacc81/ssis-integration-services-transfer-sql-server-objects-task-this-task-can-not-participate-in-a?forum=sqlintegrationservices) How this task works is it first truncates all the tables and then inserts data. So if something goes wrong second DB may end up where it has no data at all!

My question is, Is there way that we can introduce transactions or is there a different way of doing this. I'd prefer to stick to `.dtsx` rather than manual scripts because of the maintenance. But I'd like to consider all the options I have.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Based on the response in that question, the Transfer task will never support transactions... so you'll have to implement your own logic. I don't think there's any problem calling `BEGIN [DISTRIBUTED] TRANSACTION` yourself. Just make sure SSIS keeps using the same connection.